# Facebook Login JS SDK secuity

Tags: security, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I've build for my website a Facebook Login using the latest JS SDK.
However, i'm not sure how this login can be safe.

In my site i let logged in users to query my database.
In JS SDK there is no session, so how can i see if a thief with a stolen access token is quering real-user database,sending crafting packets, when the real-user is on my app?

In general, can a thief masks himself as another user and exploit user data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe if you implement login correctly.  You can learn more here about verification and other steps included in the authentication and login.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#steps

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#confirm